# Struts 2, Displaytag pagination not working

Tags: post, struts2, pagination, displaytag

I am using displaytag with struts 2 in my project, The problem is that displaytag pagination doesn't seem to work. The link generated are like 
`javascript:displaytagform('userListForm',[{f:'page',v:'2'}])` but when I click it the `page` parameter is not passed along with the request. It is not creating the hidden field `page` to store the page value, but if I add `?page=pagenum` to the URL once, then the hidden field is created and afterwards it works fine. My question is why it is not creating the field for the first time itself.

Comment: are you handling paging externally? Did you set `requesturi="someAction"` in displaytag?

Comment: @ParthTrivedi yes, I am handling externally. No, I has it inside a form,so set the `form` attribute.